# In T-SQL what is the real difference between doing a COMMIT and begin try/begin catch/rollback?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am wondering whats the difference when using T-SQL Transactions with doing a bunch of SQL statements then at the end doing a COMMIT TRAN and oppose to doing BEGIN TRY with a BEGIN CATCH that does a ROLLBACK TRAN. Surely the result is the same if there is an error. The COMMIT TRAN if there was an error won't commit at the end. And if use a BEGIN TRY/BEGIN CATCH then doing a Rollback on the BEGIN CATCH will undo what was done.

Is one method better than the other, I assume BEGIN TRY/BEGIN CATCH/ROLLBACK you have more control as oppose to a COMMIT at the end

Comment: With a TRY/CATCH you can continue after the error, the script is not aborted

Comment: You really need to read https://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using TRY/CATCH can give you an opportunity to handle errors how you would like, for example you may want to log the error in a custom table.

You can also choose to rethrow the error if some other process should handle it (like a parent stored proc), or not rethrow and deal with the problem there and then.

If you don't use TRY/CATCH you're completely at the mercy of whatever error pops up.

I also recommend reading the link @Dale posted, as the ins and outs of error handling in SQL can become more complex than you might expect.